# Blurry text in 3d transform web design

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have made [this](https://codepen.io/Mohammad_kazemzadeh/pen/BaKPPPK) pen but, texts are blurry and pixelated.
 `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`
and  `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Avoid transforms in `scale` and the `z-axis` when there's text involved. Like you do on `.front`

Comment: @thomas how can I make it 3D then?

Comment: It's a tradeoff. Use this effect and accept the blurry edges or do something else in favor of crisp text. For the container on the left I'd say, the blurryness is acceptable. The text is huge and stays (even slightly blurry) very well readable. But for the elements on the right hand side I'd favor the crispiness. There, the blurry text really messes with the readability.